# lightdm/unity-greeter wallpaper will not set

Tags: lightdm, unity-greeter

I am trying to set the wallpaper on my login screen, but i cant seem to get anything to stick.  I have used gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter background '/path/to/pic.jpg' as user 'lightdm'. However, i then get the output (process:6517): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create directory '/run/user/1000/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: could be a bug? https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-greeter/+bug/1266465

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.  Though it displays an error message, the lightdm background does in fact change to whatever new background image you set.

Open a terminal and get root

```
sudo -i
```

(Type sudo password)

Allow the user lightdm to create a connection to the X server

```
xhost +SI:localuser:lightdm
```

Switch user to lightdm.  I had to use sudo to do this, other guides do not do so.

```
sudo su lightdm -s /bin/bash
```

Make sure you have turned off the option to dynamically change lightdm's background to match the user's desktop background.

```
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-user-backgrounds 'false'
```

Finally, set your desired lightdm background.

```
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter background '/path/to/your/background.png'
```

This returns an error about dconf, ignore it. The new lightdm background should be present when you log out.  To double check, you can run

```
exit
```

twice, once to get out of lightdm and once to get out of root.  Then run

```
gsettings get com.canonical.unity-greeter background
```

Which should return the path of the image you chose.  Similarly, running

```
dconf-editor
```

Gets you to a nice GUI.  Choosing the drop-down for com, then canonical, then unity-greeter lets you check the path of lightdm's background image, and should allow you to edit it as well but I was never able to make a valid change from there.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: running

```
gsettings get com.canonical.unity-greeter background
```

after logging out does NOT return the new image path, but when lightdm is next used, the correct new image is set.  I know there's a way to run lightdm in test mode, which may be a more accurate way to test if the new background is set. I did not test that method, as the above method I used to change the background image worked for me.